# Generating a flat file with SSIS to be read by IBM z/OS program

Tags: sql-server, encoding, ssis

I am creating a fixed width text file using SSIS. The format of the flat file connection is Ragged Right. The file is generated correctly and passes all local unit tests on my Windows machine. The SSIS package then transmits the file using SFTP to a partner. The mainframe programmer at our partner claims he only can read one record. I checked what I was using for line breaks and I had chosen {CR}{LF}.

I did some research and found a couple of articles that stated that non-Windows systems would not be able to recognize CRLF as a row delimiter, but {LF} would be valid. I tried that and the programmer there still says he only detects one record even if the file has over 100 records.

Is there any additional SSIS configuration I am missing in my Flat File Connection? Could it be an encoding issue?

Comment: Do you have an agreed upon layout for the flat file? That should include what you should be using as the row delimiter and if it should be part of the fixed width.  You can open the file with a Hex editor and take a look and compare it to your layout and have your partner do the same and compare against what he is expecting to see.  This sounds like it will be hard for anyone to solve without knowing exactly what the problem is

Comment: A good, free hex editor can be found here - http://www.belkaplan.de/opera/tools/xvi32.htm if you need one.

Comment: I tried this, my file has 0d0a which is carriage return line feed, one of his files that he claims works simply has "20" which I guess is just hex for space. Now he thinks I should send the file in ebcdic...I'm sending in ascii..

Comment: a Hex 20 is an Ascii space, in Ebcdic it's a DS or Digit Select.  That hex editor I linked will do an Ebcdic convert, although it may not be perfect if you have any special characters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In cases like this I find it useful to request a small sample file so that you can match your output to it, using a hex editor to verify all the special characters.  If a sample file is not possible then narrow down your results to 2 or 3 and work with your counterpart to get the format correct even if it means you are manually altering the file with the hex editor until you get it correct, then you can tackle the programmatic file creation.

Your mileage may vary, but right now it would seem you are programming without a complete spec, and that's going to make your job a huge headache if not totally impossible.

Good Luck!

Comment: So the eventual solution was this: I was using winScp because SSIS doesn't natively support sFTP, so I was calling winScp in my package to transmit the file. Out of a whim, I decided to change the transfer mode to binary and it worked. Since it was a text file I thought ASCII mode was correct, but I guess it works now so everyone is happy. I don't claim to understand the internals of why this fixed cross platform row delimiting issues. For those interested the row delimiter for the flat file connection was {CR}{LF}. Maybe someone will run into this one day...